# Call a viewcontroller present in a framework form my current project

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have been trying to call a view controller present in my Framework's story board from a demo project. I am not able to do so and it ends up with following **error** :

**Could not find a storyboard named 'checkoAuthFrameworkStoryBoard' in bundle NSBundle**

My code :

Current project from where I am trying to open the Framework's view controller :

```
if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "co.transpacks.checkoAuthFramework") {
                MyFrameworkCoordinator.instantiateFrameworkStoryboard(controller: self, bundle: bundle)
            }
```

Framework's public class which is being called :

```
public class MyFrameworkCoordinator {
    public static func instantiateFrameworkStoryboard(controller: UIViewController,bundle: Bundle) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "checkoAuthFrameworkStoryBoard", bundle: bundle)
            let scanVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScanViewController") as! ScanViewController
            
            controller.present(scanVC.self, animated: true, completion: {
                
            })
    }
    
}
```

The error is coming when code is reaching :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "checkoAuthFrameworkStoryBoard", bundle: bundle)
```

please help.

EDIT :

**compiled storyboard file name**

[image: compiled storyboard file name image]

Comment: Have you verified the bundle identifier? Have you verified the storyboard name (case matters too)? Have you verified the storyboard is actually part of the built framework?

Comment: @HangarRash Yes all the three are verified i.e bundle identifier, storyboard name (including the case) and storyboard being part of bundle resources in the framework project.

Comment: One of those must be wrong otherwise you wouldn't be getting the error.

Comment: @HangarRash Added a screenshot for reference. I don't think the error is due to any of the three you mentioned.

Comment: If you use a development pod, do you try to rebuild the framework?

Comment: @son no. I always clear the build folder and then build it again.